# jQuery: link doesn't work after .toggle()

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle

I've just build a dropdown menu which I would like to drop down on a click, and go back up after an other click. This perfectly works with a toggle I have used, but the problem is that after the dropdown, the links don't execute.

$(function() {

```
    $("#nav_menu-2 ul.menu ul").css({ display: 'none' });


    $("#nav_menu-2 ul.menu #testbutton").toggle(function() {


        $(this).find('ul.sub-menu')
            .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "show", "opacity": "show" }, 300 );
    }, function(){

        $(this).find('ul.sub-menu')
            .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "hide", "opacity": "hide" }, 300 );
    });

});
```

So my geuss is that after the menu has dropped, it goes back up on a click, instead of executing the link. But since I'm quite new to javascript/jQuery, I have no idea what other option I have. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would instead use [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), bound to the click event of the button that should open the menu:

```
$("#nav_menu-2 ul.menu #testbutton").click(function() {
  $('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

You might have to change the selectors slightly depending how your menu is constructed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known side-effect of [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). The documentation says:

> The implementation also calls `.preventDefault()` on the event, so links
>   will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked if `.toggle()` has
>   been called on the element.

To work around that, you will have to bind to `click` instead of `toggle`. As Andrew says, you can use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to obtain the same behavior from a `click` event.